# RPi dashing.io ERROR: failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to set up dashing.io on my raspberry pi using this guide: https://github.com/mivok/squirrelpouch/wiki/dashing-pi

I install ruby-dev using `sudo apt-get install ruby ruby-dev` and than dashing using `echo 'gem: --no-rdoc --no-ri' >> ~/.gemrc
sudo gem install bundler dashing`

During the installastion of dashing I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Error installing dashing:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/ext/gem_make.out`
```

I've found several similar posts about this error, but every solution to those is to install ruby-dev, which I have done already. I have also tried to run `sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-dev`. This command tells me that this version of ruby-dev is already installed. I've also tried to run `rails -v`, but get `-bash: rails: command not found`

What else can I do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: what says the `gem_make.out`?

Comment: It says only `/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb`

Comment: no, please show containment of `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1-0-3/ext/gem_make.out`

Comment: I noticed a typing error in the path there, it is supposed to be `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/ext/gem_make.out`

When I do `nano /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/ext/gem_make.out` i only see `/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb`in the output.

See screenshot iat http://tangeland.net/pics/gem_make.out.jpg

Comment: just can advice you not to use root, and use `rvm/rbenv` and `bundler` to install gems, so install `rvm` then install ruby with `rvm`, then: `mkdir proj; cd proj; echo "2.1.4" > .ruby-version; echo 'proj' > .ruby-gemset; cd .. ; cd proj`